# How can I intergrate SiriKit using Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, siri, sirikit

I am working on an iOS app similar to Uber and wish to integrate SiriKit to perform various in app functions like requesting a cab, the app has been made using Objective-C and I wish to integrate the SiriKit. What is the best possible way to do that. I am afraid I might not be able to switch to Swift.

Comment: hii did u figured out in Objective c?

Answer (score 3):

The Apple Developer documentation has code samples in both Objective-C and Swift.  Your question is very broad, so I would start by looking through the documentation that they provide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/

On this site, it is better to ask specific questions, along with code samples showing what you have tried, rather than broad questions basically asking for a full tutorial.

Answer (score -2):

You misundestood SiriKit concept. It based on usage of "Intents extension". to handle intents you free to use objective-c.
Please refer to [manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/CreatingtheIntentsExtension.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH4-SW1)

Comment: You could not use voice recognition of Siri inside the app, instead you should create intent that will be shown when user ask siri to get a ride somewhere. If user chose this intent from siri suggestions than iOS run you app.